# Any php string function to do something like this?

Tags: php, php-5.2

```
$length = strlen($s);

if($length == 10)
{

  $newval = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
  {

    $newval .= $s[$i];

    if($i == 2 || $i == 5)  
    {
       $newval .= '-';
    }

  }

}
```

If anybody knows what kind of a string function I would use, please let me know.

Comment: What does that code do? I'm lazy to run it.

Comment: -1 for assuming we should know what that code does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple string operation should be kept simple, so go with the most straight forward solution:

```
$str = substr($input, 0, 3).'-'.substr($input, 3, 3).'-'.substr($input, 6);
```

But as usually, there are several ways to skin a cat, so you have options. Like:

```
$str = sprintf('%s-%s-%s', substr($input, 0, 3), substr($input, 3, 3), substr($input, 6));
```

Or alternatively

```
$str = preg_replace('/^(.{3})(.{3})(.*)$/', '\1-\2-\3', $input);
```

Or alternatively

```
$str = preg_split('//', $input);

if (5 > count($chrs)) {
   array_splice($chrs, 4, 0, '-');
}

if (3 > count($chrs)) {
   array_splice($chrs, 2, 0, '-');
}

$str = implode('', $chrs);
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to accomplish this:

```
if(strlen($s) == 10) {
   $s = substr($s, 0, 3) . '-' . substr($s, 3, 3) . '-' . substr($s, 6);
}
```

[**codepad example**](http://codepad.org/2aFPZqEe)

Answer (score 0):

substr ?

```
if(strlen($s) == 10)
{
   $newval.=substr($s,0,3)."-".substr($s,3,3)."-".substr($s,6,4);
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `length` argument on the last `substr` call if you already know what the length of the entire string is! :)